# Oracle - Error on EXCHANGE PARTITION with List-Range partitioning

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I'm trying to use EXCHANGE PARTITION on following example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE_00(
    CONTACT_ID NUMBER,
    SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAG NUMBER, 
    SOURCE_SYSTEM VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
    START_DATE DATE, 
    ACTIVE NUMBER,
    SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAGS NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ACTIVE || SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAG) VIRTUAL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_temp_table_00 PRIMARY KEY (CONTACT_ID))  

PARTITION BY LIST (SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAGS) 
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (START_DATE)
( PARTITION p_ac_00 VALUES ('00') 
  ( SUBPARTITION sp_ac_00_before_2014  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.01.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
    SUBPARTITION sp_ac_00_201401       VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
  )    
)
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

create table TARGET_TABLE(
    CONTACT_ID NUMBER, 
    SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAG NUMBER, 
    SOURCE_SYSTEM VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
    START_DATE DATE, 
    ACTIVE NUMBER,
    SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAGS NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ACTIVE || SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAG) VIRTUAL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_target_table PRIMARY KEY (CONTACT_ID))  
PARTITION BY LIST (secondary_contact_flags) 
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (START_DATE)
( PARTITION p_ac_00 VALUES ('00') 
  ( SUBPARTITION sp_ac_00_before_2014  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.01.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
    SUBPARTITION sp_ac_00_201401       VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
   ),
  PARTITION p_ac_10 VALUES ('10') 
  ( SUBPARTITION sp_ac_10_before_2014  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.01.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
    SUBPARTITION sp_ac_10_201401       VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))

  ),
  PARTITION p_ac_01 VALUES ('01') 
  ( SUBPARTITION sp_ac_01_before_2014  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.01.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
    SUBPARTITION sp_ac_01_201401       VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))

  ),
  PARTITION p_ac_11 VALUES ('11') 
  ( SUBPARTITION sp_ac_11_before_2014  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.01.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
    SUBPARTITION sp_ac_11_201401       VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))

  )
)
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

INSERT INTO DM_KSCTSC.TEMP_TABLE_00 (CONTACT_ID, SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAG, SOURCE_SYSTEM, START_DATE, ACTIVE) VALUES (1, 0, 'ABC', TO_DATE('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD'), 0);
commit;
```

When trying to exchange partitions:

```
alter table target_table exchange partition p_ac_00 with table TEMP_TABLE_00 without validation;
```

even though the structure of the partitions are identical, Oracle returns an

> ORA-14292: Partitioning type of table must match subpartitioning type
>   of composite partition

Is there another solution than exchanging every subpartition seperately?

Comment: you may want to check this: http://www.ypl.com/oracle/manuals/sql_ref/alter_table/html_deep/bk01ch12s01s06s06s06s02.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to exchange partition between a partition table (PT) and a non-partitioned table (TMP) the TMP table must have **the same structure as the partition of PT**.

I.e. if the PT is partitioned, the TMP is non-partitioned.

If the PT is composit partitioned, the TMP is partitioned in the same way as the subpartition of PT.

In your case is the problem in the TMP table (TEMP_TABLE_00), it must be **partitioned by RANGE** (same as the subpartition of TARGET_TABLE)

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE_00(
    CONTACT_ID NUMBER,
    SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAG NUMBER, 
    SOURCE_SYSTEM VARCHAR2(10 CHAR), 
    START_DATE DATE, 
    ACTIVE NUMBER,
    SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAGS NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ACTIVE || SECONDARY_CONTACT_FLAG) VIRTUAL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_temp_table_00 PRIMARY KEY (CONTACT_ID))  

PARTITION BY  RANGE (START_DATE)
  
  (  PARTITION sp_ac_00_before_2014  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.01.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
     PARTITION sp_ac_00_201401       VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE ('01.02.2014', 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
  )    
 
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```

In this setup the exchange partition works.